# Regural expression extractor in jmeter

Tags: regex, jmeter

I want to parse the string inside the square bracket from the following string

XX [1xx93y6:1487xx20480:012]. YYY MMM

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Did you try anything? Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

JMeter uses [Jakarta ORO](http://jakarta.apache.org/oro/) as regex pattern matching mechanism which provides Perl5-compatible regular expressions.

In order to extract entity in square brackets do the following:

1. Add a [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) as a child of the sampler, which produces that string
2. Configure it as follows:

   - Reference name: anything meaningful, i.e. `string`
   - Regular Expression: `\[(.+?)\]`
   - Template: `$1$`
   - Remaining fields can be left intact.

Refer extracted value as `${string}` or `${__V(string)}` where required.

You can also use [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener to test your regular expressions right against response without having to re-execute the test as at image below:

[image: Regex Tester]

See [Using Regular Expressions in JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-regular-expressions-jmeter) for more details on how to perform correlation using Regular Expression Extractor.